# command \thead already defined

Tags: tables, tabularx, xltabular

command `thead` already defined

```
\documentclass[twoside,mtp]{iiitg}
%koeradoera added lines here below
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    %koeradoera added above 3 lines
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage{makecell,tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
    %\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
    \usepackage{xltabular}
    \newcommand{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
    %above line added by koeradoera
    %%
```

I am getting error

```
Command \thead already defined. ...ead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: You are loading the `makecell` package, the documentation of which starts with "This package helps to create common layout for tabular material. The `\thead` command, based on one-column tabular environment, is offered for creation of tabular column heads." Even thought some users seem to like to hack basic commands or to do something like `\newcommanc{\ul}{...}`, I recommend not touching basic commands. Please consider using macro names that are not used in major packages.

Comment: ohh thanks so instead of thead some thing \koderahead can do the needful I think

Comment: Yes, something like that. As a rule of thumb (with several important counterexamples like `\DeclareMathOperator` or `\NewDocumentCommand`) "standard" (La)TeX commands tend to be composed of lower-case letters, so if you do something like `\MyThead` you should be fine (no guarantee).

Comment: commands already existing --like `\thead`--are protected